# FLANN and big HDF5 file

Tags: c++, hdf5, nearest-neighbor, knn, flann

I'm trying to use [flann](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/) with big hdf5 file (dimensions 1kk x 1k).

But all fails on function in flann_example.cpp

```
Matrix<float> dataset;
load_from_file(dataset, "carray.hdf5", "carray");
```

on line

```
dataset = flann::Matrix<T>(new T[dims_out[0]*dims_out[1]], dims_out[0], dims_out[1]);
```

because it seems that it wants to allocate big memory chunk with `new`

I'm using win32 with 2 Gb.Is there any way to process such big data?

I also tried with python

```
def using_pyflann():
    N=10000*6  # for 100k x 1k don't work
    dim=1000
    type=np.int32  #int8 can't be used?
    x = np.array(np.random.rand(N, dim)*10, dtype=type)
    perm = np.random.permutation(N)
    fl= FLANN()
    fl.build_index(x)
    pt= np.array(np.random.rand(1, dim)*10, dtype=type)
    t0= time.time()
    res, dist= fl.nn_index(pt)
    print (time.time()-t0)
    print res
    print dist
    print 'done'
```

Comment: You're going to have to read it piece by piece, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no particular reason, that you have to use win32 solution paltform, you should switch to x64 platform. On Win32 platform you can't allocate more than about 2GB memory.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memory-limits-applications-windows